# Get the week correspoding to a day

Tags: android

I am trying to get the week corresponding to a date. For example if I placed 2012 dec: 24 I want to get the week from sun: to sat and this week should contain dec24.

I tried several codes. Currently I am using this code

```java
public static String[] getpreviousweek(int num) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Set the calendar to monday of the current week
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, num * 7);
        // Print dates of the current week starting on Monday
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String[] days = new String[7];

          for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
             {
                  days[i] = df.format(c.getTime());
                   c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
             } 
     return days;
 }
```

Comment: What are your input parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify above code as below

```
public static String[] getpreviousweek(Calendar calendar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Calendar c = calendar;
        // Set the calendar to monday of the current week
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, num * 7);
        // Print dates of the current week starting on Monday
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String[] days = new String[7];

          for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
             {
                  days[i] = df.format(c.getTime());
                   c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
             } 
     return days;
 }
```

And call this method as

```
Calendar inputDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
 inputDate.set(2012, Calendar.DECEMBER, 24);
 String[] dates = getpreviousweek(inputDate);
```

Comment: the thing is I want to get the next week on swipe.. if  I palce this code hopefully I can modify tha

Answer (score 0):

First find current day of week and get startDate of week as well as EndDate of that particular week.

```
try {
        String yourDateString="10-12-2015";
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        Date yourDate=df.parse(yourDateString);
        c.setTime(yourDate);
        int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        Log.e("day", "" + dayOfWeek);

        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfWeek * -1);
        Log.e("startDate", c.getTime().toString());
        Date startDate=c.getTime();
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
        Log.e("endDate", c.getTime().toString());
        Date endDate=c.getTime();

}
catch(Exception  e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and then you can have list of days for that week.

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(startDate);
while (calendar.getTime().before(endDate))
{
    Date result = calendar.getTime();
    dates.add(result);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
dates.add(calendar.getTime());
for(int i=0;i<dates.size();i++)
{
     System.out.print("Day " + (i+1) + " = " + dates.get(i).toString());
}
```